# Is it possible to create custom ISO with Cubic and use autoinstall?

Tags: system-installation, 20.04, iso, preseed

I would like to prepare custom Ubuntu 20.04 image. The idea is that system after automatic installation will include some custom network configuration, Docker and some Docker containers running.
My idea is to use Cubic tool to:

- install an additional software like docker,
- install desktop environment as I need it assuming that I will base on Ubuntu 20.04 server,
- put custom docker images in the final ISO.
  I thought about using preseed file to load and start some docker containers and apply some additional custom network configuration. However, I read that I should rather stick to autoinstall and not use preseed anymore. Is it possible to still use Cubic to customize ISO and then autoinstall to automatize installation to achieve my scenario? Is it possible to include autoinstall config directly in the ISO using Cubic and use it during the system installation?